# Wordpress Install on OS X Snow-Leopard under Sites/public for use with capistrano

Tags: wordpress, osx-snow-leopard, capistrano

I would like to put my local OS X wordpress site in my **~users/Sites/public directory**, instead of the **~users/Sites** so i can properly setup a capistrano deployment.

When i try this i can visit the site locally by visiting **http://localhost/public**  and everything looks and works great but if i ever try to go to **http://localhost/public/wp-admin** to administer my local copy of wordpress it tries to redirect me back to **http://localhost/wp-admin** which doesn't exist.

Do you know how I might be able to work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a symlink. In the terminal:

```
cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/
sudo ln -s ~/Sites/public/wp-admin
```

Then type your user password when prompted.

Comment: I still keep getting redirected when i try to go to localhost/public/wp-admin

Comment: It didn't, I ended up having to re-install wordpress which fixed the issue. I appreciate you following up.

Comment: Sure. If you have a solution which was better than mine, you should post it as an answer to your question and accept it... of course I don't mind the +15 rep, but if others have the same issue, accepting your own answer will show them what actually worked. You also get a badge if enough people upvote your answer (2 I think)

Comment: If someone reads the comments for this, they will get the solution. Plus i appreciate you answering, also for replying. If my solution was more substantial I may have posted an **answer**.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your DocumentRoot in your Apache config would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: I modified **/etc/apache2/httpd.conf** to contain DocumentRoot "/Users/<user>/Sites/public" and then restarted the server **sudo apachectl restart** any other configurations you can think of?